# shape context matching technique

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to implement shape context matching algorithm which is

1. Calculate the distance of a point to all other points.
2. Normalize the distance by mean distance.
3. Create logarithmic distance scale for normalized distances.
4. Create distance histogram: Iterate for each scale incrementing bins when
   bins with higher numbers describe points closer together.
5. Calculate angle between all points.
6. Bin angles which is slightly different than distance.
7. Matching - Cost Matrix: Calculate cost of matching each point to every
   other point.
8. Matching - Additional Cost Terms:
             Surrounding Texture Difference,
              Tangent Angle Difference.
9. Matching: Find pairing of points that leads to least total cost according
   to equation 3

I'm now in step 3, and I don't know how to calculate log distance scale

Example:

if we have coordinates in shape as:

0.2000   0.5000

0.4000   0.5000

0.3000   0.4000

0.1500   0.3000

0.3000   0.2000

0.4500   0.3000

**step(1): Euclidean distance from each point to all others:**

0          0.2000      0.1414       0.2062      0.3162      0.3202

0.2000     0           0.1414       0.3202      0.3162       0.2062

0.1414     0.1414      0            0.1803      0.2000       0.1803

0.2062     0.3202     0.1803         0          0.1803       0.3000

0.3162     0.3162     0.2000       0.1803        0           0.1803

0.3202     0.2062     0.1803       0.3000       0.1803          0

**step(2):Normalized distances between each point:**

0 1.0623 0.7511 1.0949 1.6796 1.7004

1.0623 0 0.7511 1.7004 1.6796 1.0949

0.7511 0.75110 0.9575 1.0623 0.9575

1.0949 1.7004 0.9575 0 0.9575 1.5934

1.6796 1.6796 1.0623 0.9575 0 0.9575

1.7004 1.0949 0.9575 1.5934 0.9575 0

I don't know how to create log distance scale where

The log distance scale for normalized distances (closer = more discriminate):

0.1250     0.2500     0.5000     1.0000      2.0000

Any one help me?

Comment: I can't understand your last few lines.... Could you define the "log distance scale" and explain what are `0.1250 0.2500 0.5000 1.0000 2.0000`?

Comment: and me too, I don't know what's log distance scale mean? after computed Euclidean distance and Normalized it, I found this line " The log distance scale for normalized distances (closer = more discriminate)":
0.1250 0.2500 0.5000 1.0000 2.0000
and I can't understand how to compute it, you can see in this link http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~grauman/courses/spring2008/slides/ShapeContexts425.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I have no background in shape context, and here's my thinking:

The teacher wants to measure the distance in a way that fits the need by shape context. To achieve this,

(step 3) First build a scale (aka a ruler). The scale has 5 bins, namely `0~0.1250`, `0.1250~0.2500`, `0.2500~0.5000`, `0.5000~1.0000`, `1.0000~2.0000`. The maximum range should cover the maximum value in your data of normalized distance (`1.7004` here). This scale is increasing logarithmically (I mean "exponentially"). I still have no idea about "closer = more discriminate".

(step 4) throw each data value into different bins, using the scale. The teacher uses iteration method, which works; but essentially you just need to find some way to categorize the values.

I think you can also achieve it in this way:

```
>> x = rand(1,10)*2;ceil(log2(ceil(x/.125)))+1,x

ans =

     2     1     5     5     5     3     5     4     1     4


x =

    0.1517    0.1079    1.0616    1.5583    1.8680    0.2598    1.1376    0.9388    0.0238    0.6742
```

So you are finding logarithm of distance *to base 0.125*.